# What is the sense of the is.single() function in R?

Tags: r, function

I stumbled on the function `is.single()` and do not understand what is does. The description says:

> is.single reports an error. There are no single precision values in R.

And indeed, if I try to test different things inside the function I get an error. Example:

```
is.single(1)
Error in is.single(1) : type "single" unimplemented in R
```

I see no sense in a function that seemingly always gives an error. What is the function for?

Comment: could be for s compatibility but [definitely](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7b29057a67f3695f31713eb19de0328bdffb7407/src/main/names.c#L613) will always [throw an error](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0e1d31dcc232c0b4a7c96651ba4d76b3baca8264/src/main/coerce.c#L2133:L2134) in r

Comment: As you said, it does nothing than give an error. It looks that is an inerited function from the first versions. Since R uses double presicion, it is useless in only R context. By the way, it exist the function 'simple()', wich the description says "R has no single precision data type. All real numbers are stored in double precision format. The functions as.single and single are identical to as.double and double except they set the attribute Csingle that is used in the .C and .Fortran interface, and they are intended only to be used in that context".